# Getting documention to appear in intellitext window using eclispe and java

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation, javadoc

When using the standard api, for example the collections library, the predictive text options windows also shows the comments on class/methods.

however when I do the same style comments on my own code - the open project I am working on (code completion works correctly, just no comments appear), and then reference it later. These comments are not displayed. I get the correct code completion options, just none of the associated comments/documentation. They are not in jar, they are source files, that are built using maven into a war file.

Is there a setting I need to enable in eclipse, or do I need to set up javadoc or something ?

Comment: Do you have "your own" code as a dependent eclipse project (or the same project)? Or do you mean jars?

Comment: its the open project, the code compeltion works correctly - none of the comments I put on appear in the window, next to the code completion options. whereas normally you get two windows, one for code compeltion, the second then shows the comments for each method you highlight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How embarassing, you to have to specify double asterix at the begininng of comment to create a  [javdoc comment](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/javadoc/)

```
/**
* read the documentation before asking questions on stackoverlow
*/
```

Comment: (I blame Eclipse auto-generated "non-javadoc" comments on overrides for people forgetting this...)

Answer (score 0):

If the class  is part of a jar you need to associate the javadoc jar or path.  You can right click on the jar in eclipse and specify the path in the properties dialog.